# Laravel push or pull architecture

Tags: laravel-5.1

I know that Laravel framework follows the model–view–controller (MVC) pattern but I don't really understand if it implements Pull or Push Architecture. 
Ty in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can say that its uses the Push Architecture.

when you enter a url it's goes like(very simplified example) routes->controller->view

you can read more about the [Request Lifecycle](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/lifecycle)

Comment: ok...I asked because I thought that it uses both. I mean, for example, when a user wants a list of resource the view send the request and pull the data from the controllers, instead when he submits a request for a specific action (for example post in a submit form), the controllers push the result of that action.

Comment: why does it matter? you can do whatever you want in all php frameworks.. you can always fire a request from js to php in all frameworks